# How do I recover my photos

Tags: external-sd

i have Samsung galaxy gt-s7562 phone. i was wanting to reduce my phone memory. my photos and videos have all been cleared. i would like to know to recover them from my phone.

Comment: How did you clear them/reduce your phone memory? A factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the external SD card to a PC and try a recovery software like Recuva(or any other recovery software for that matter) and see what it can recover.